# iOS: Fetching Location of the Photos from a WKWebview

Tags: ios, security, webview, location, photo-gallery

I have build an iOS app where I am loading an HTML page from local resources in a WKWebView. I want to load the photos clicked at a specific location from photo gallery in the WKWebView. I am able to open the photo gallery but not getting the location of the photos.

I understand that iOS 10 onwards, these details cannot be fetched if the connection is insecure (over http). But not clear as to why it is not getting loaded even when the page is being loaded locally from the resources.

Any pointers?

Comment: Please share your code how you are trying to load photos to wkwebview?

Comment: I am accessing the photos in HTML code. I just bundled the html file in my Resources folder and loaded it in WKWebView